# Duplication of record with SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I have the following code in an access database for copying data to a new record:

```
    mySQL = "INSERT INTO Detail_tbl ( [Index], [Section], [Group], [Detail], [No Samples], CPS, [Detail Status], Date_added, [Job Number] )" & _
            " SELECT Detail_tbl.Index, Detail_tbl.Section, Detail_tbl.Group, Detail_tbl.Detail, Detail_tbl.[No Samples], Detail_tbl.CPS, Detail_tbl.[Detail Status], Now() AS Expr2, Left([Job Number],10) AS Expr1" & _
            " FROM Detail_tbl" & _
            " WHERE (((Left([Detail_tbl].[Job Number],10))=[Forms]![NewWork]![Job_Number]))"
    
    DoCmd.RunSQL mySQL
    Me.Job_Details.Enabled = True
    Me.[Job Details].Requery
```

Problem is, it copies everything twice. It is not that it is adding to an already existing record as without the above code, nothing is recorded at all. The code is used to change a record from a quotation to an active job where extra information is required. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you want to change (update) a job, wouldn't that be an UPDATE query, not an INSERT query?

Comment: None of both, queries always start with "select" and do not change data.

Comment: How does this code get executed? if it is in an event procedure (for example), it can be triggered several times.